# Multiplication of Data Array Python

Tags: python, numpy

**Hello guys**

I want to ask, for example, we have data:
data = [12,3,4,5,12,5,64,31,42]. After that, I want to multiply the data: times = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0]

What I want to ask is, there are 9 values ​​multiplied by 7 values, so how do the scores continue? if it continues: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: `data` and `times` need to be the same length. You can repeat `times` array using [numpy.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and then *clip* it so it has the same length as `data`. And then you can multiply them.

Comment: `data` and `times` look like lists.  They cannot be multiplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cycle` from `itertools` if you want the values to be repeated, and do the multiplication using list comprehension:

```py
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> [i*j for i,j in zip(data, cycle(times))]

#output: [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42]
```